# VBA merge non-adjacent cells containing same text in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am building a calendar in Excel that automatically maps event information from a table to a dynamic calendar view. Each row represents a time from 8AM - 6PM, and each column represents a day of the week from Sunday - Saturday. I was able to map information for each unique event to two separate cells in each column, one for start time and one for end time. I am looking for help with building a macro to merge the cells containing the same information into one so the calendar is cohesive. E.g. Event A starts at 9AM and ends at 11AM. There is currently one cell populated at 9AM and one at 11AM, but the cell for 10AM is blank and I'd like to merge the two populated cells from the 9AM cell to 11AM cell. As the populated cells will not always be adjacent, the offset function doesn't seem to work in this case.

Here is the pseudo code I'm trying to accomplish:

1. For each column in a specified region
2. loop through each row
3. if two cells contain identical text
4. merge those two cells

Here is the little bit of code I've managed to come up with so far. You can tell there are many gaps and probably syntax errors:

```
Sub MergeCells
Dim cells As String
cells = ActiveSheet.Range("C8:V28,C31:V51,C54:V74,C77:V97,C100:V120")
    If ActiveSheet.Range(cells).??? Then
       ActiveSheet.Range(cells).Merge
    End If 
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Before picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T79sN.jpg)

[After picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U41Rx.jpg)

Comment: If which two cells contain identical text? The cell above and/or below? Or would it always be above? Can you post some sample data and sample of expected output?

Comment: As @BruceWayne stated, a before and after picture would most definitely help here

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to embed images yet, but I have attached before and after pictures in my original post. As you can see the position of the cell will vary depending on the start and end times of the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - this may be overkill, and you may need to tweak, but this was fun to work on.

```
Sub combine_Same()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim tableRng As Range
Dim i As Long, k As Long, lastRow As Long
Dim curText As Range, prevText As Range

Dim tableRanges As Variant

tableRanges = Split("b3:e20,C31:V51,C54:V74,C77:V97,C100:V120", ",")

Dim rng     As Long

For rng = LBound(tableRanges) To UBound(tableRanges)
    Debug.Print "Working with: " & tableRanges(rng)
    Set tableRng = Range(tableRanges(rng))
'    tableRng.Select
    lastRow = tableRng.Rows(tableRng.Rows.Count).Row
    For k = tableRng.Columns(1).Column To tableRng.Columns.Count
        For i = lastRow To tableRng.Rows(1).Row Step -1
            Set curText = Cells(i, k)
            Set prevText = curText.End(xlUp)
            If curText.Value = prevText.Value And Not IsEmpty(curText) Then
                'curText.Select
                Range(curText, prevText).Merge
                curText.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            ElseIf curText.Value = curText.Offset(-1, 0).Value And Not IsEmpty(curText) Then
                'curText.Select
                Range(curText, curText.Offset(-1, 0)).Merge
                curText.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            End If
        Next i
    Next k
Next rng
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: one small change I made:
    lastRow = tableRng.Rows(tableRng.Rows.Count).Row
    lastColumn= tableRng.Columns(tableRng.Columns.Count).Column
    For k = tableRng.Columns(1).Column To lastColumn

not sure why this made a difference, but it covered the last column that wasn't updating before.